# How to prevent System.Timers.Timer from queuing for execution on a thread pool?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading, timer

There is a problem with standard System.Timers.Timer behaviour. The timer raise Elapsed event with some interval. But when time of execution inside Elapsed event handler exceed timer interval then thread pool begin queuing event handling. This is a problem in my case. This is because with my Elapsed event handler I fetch some data from database and doing something with it and finally save results back to database. But data handling should be provided only once. So, is there a way to prevent from queuing elapse events for System.Timers.Timer.

As illustration for this issue you can consider next test program:

```
public class EntryPoint
{

    private static void TimeProc(object state, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Current time {0} on the thread {1}", DateTime.Now, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(20000);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> for finishing\n\n");
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10);
        System.Timers.Timer MyTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        MyTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimeProc);
        MyTimer.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
        MyTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

And possible output will be as here:

```
Current time 03.02.2011 0:00:09 on the thread 4
Current time 03.02.2011 0:00:10 on the thread 5
Current time 03.02.2011 0:00:12 on the thread 6
Current time 03.02.2011 0:00:13 on the thread 7
Current time 03.02.2011 0:00:14 on the thread 8
Current time 03.02.2011 0:00:15 on the thread 9
Current time 03.02.2011 0:00:16 on the thread 10
Current time 03.02.2011 0:00:17 on the thread 11
Current time 03.02.2011 0:00:18 on the thread 12
Current time 03.02.2011 0:00:19 on the thread 13
Current time 03.02.2011 0:00:30 on the thread 4
Current time 03.02.2011 0:00:30 on the thread 5
```

**Possible solutions:**

1) It  was inspired by:[C# Timer vs Thread in Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474694/c-timer-vs-thread-in-service)

And has a code like here regarding to mentioned above sample:

```
    public class EntryPoint
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer MyTimer;
        private static void TimeProc(object state, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current time {0} on the thread {1}", DateTime.Now, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
            MyTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> for finishing\n\n");
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10);
            MyTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            MyTimer.AutoReset = false;

            MyTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimeProc);
            MyTimer.Enabled = true;
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

2) Second way is about SynchronizingObject, but it is a valuable only for Windows form application or required additional development of code for implementing object that would be implements ISynchronizeInvoke interface. More about this way you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841345/synchronizingobject-for-an-event)

So, for now I will prefer first solution.

Comment: the timer doesn't have a problem... this occurs all over the place. It's actually nice that it queues up Elapsed events. if this were a hardware interrupt you'd blow your interval and you can't get that back.

Comment: If the data should only be handled once then why the repeating timer or do you mean at most once every X time?

Comment: @Chris In my case another application save some data to a database and my application should read it and handle.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What I usually do in this case is stop the timer at the start of the `Elapsed` handler and start it again at the end. This way, you are only handling one tick at a time.

**UPDATE:**

Per the MSDN link, I think what they mean is that you can set your own flag (but still have the ticks come in), but thread safety measures should be taken as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But it seems not a right way, due to the fact that it required additional resource for stoping and starting timer.

Comment: @apros: The behavior you are experiencing is by design. If you set a timer to tick every thirty seconds for a minute, you would expect two ticks events to be fired, right? If you want it to behave differently, this is the way to do it.

Comment: MSDN claim here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx "One way to resolve this race condition is to set a flag that tells the event handler for the Elapsed event to ignore subsequent events. ". So, I hope, there should exists another way to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you take this approach, you want to restart your timer in a finally block.  Otherwise, you may get an exception while processing and the timer will never restart.  For this and a few other reasons, I don't think this is a good approach.

Comment: This snippet is very flawed, it isn't thread-safe.  Interlocked is required.  Review MSDN example code in the Timer.Stop() method docs.

Comment: @Hans: I realize that it is not thread-safe which is why I noted at the end that the point I was trying to make was how to use the flag that MSDN mentioned, but that thread-safety measures should be taken.

Answer (score 4):

I would say simply stop it and then start it after your lengthy execution like this.

```
tmr.Stop();
//Your lengthy execution code goes here
tmr.Start();
```

Comment: It's usally what I do however you should also be aware of this when using stop : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop.aspx the part at the begining in yellow warn the user from a second lunch while stopping.

Comment: @Chris if you were talking about thread none in his case but me not long a go I worked with a tomer in my servie and I had to be able to capture other events while letting my execution code finish. That's why I started to talk about it.

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro if you are aware of it you can remove the handler from the delegate before stopping the timer no ?

Comment: i know.. but never tried.. seems like a good idea... i'll check it out.. Thanx

Comment: This doesn't work, two Elapsed calls can be pending at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you are seeing is by design.  Either set a [SynchronizingObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) on the timer, or use another timer (such as [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)) that doesn't tick on multiple threads.

Comment: the information you give regarding System.Threading.Timer is incorrect. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx - "The callback method executed by the timer should be reentrant, because it is called on ThreadPool threads. The callback can be executed simultaneously on two thread pool threads if the timer interval is less than the time required to execute the callback, or if all thread pool threads are in use and the callback is queued multiple times."


Perhaps you were instead thinking of System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: additionally, setting a synchronization object (if my understanding is correct) will not prevent queuing, it will just limit it to processing them one at a time out of the queue. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx for a comparison of timers that goes into some detail on the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I just create a static flag variable.  This way my timer keeps running, but the code is simply  bypassed if it the method has not completed before the next timer cycle.

In the method used for the timer, test if an event is in progress.

```
Timer_Method_Called()
{
  if (eventInProgress == 0)
  {
     // flag event as in progress
     eventInProcess == 1;

     // perform code....

     // after code is complete, allow the method to execute
     eventInProgress == 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not thread safe, and you are using == for what I'm assuming you meant to be your assignments (=).

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the answers are thread safe, let me propose one that is:

```
void oneHundredMS_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {

  if (setTimerBodyRunning()) { //only proceed to body if it is not already processing; setTimerBodyRunning must be thread-safe
    // here you do your long running operation
    setTimerBodyFinished();
  }
}
```

As you can see, the timer handler first checks to see if it is not already running, and only proceeds to the body if false is returned.  If true is returned, then the handler quickly returns and ticks do not queue (which they would have had a simple lock statement been used). Here are the definitions for setTimerBodyRunning and setTimerBodyFinished:

```
private bool setTimerBodyRunning() {
        bool retVal = false;
        lock (timerBodyRunning) { //timerBodyRunning is type object and it holds a bool.  
            //The reason it is object and not bool is so it can be locked on to ensure thread safety
            if (!((bool)timerBodyRunning)) {
                timerBodyRunning = true;
                retVal = true;
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

private void setTimerBodyFinished() {
    lock (timerBodyRunning) {
        timerBodyRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Here's how you'd initialize and start the timer:

```
object timerBodyRunning = new object();
timerBodyRunning = false;
System.Timers.Timer timerFrequency100MS = new System.Timers.Timer();
timerFrequency100MS.Interval = FREQUENCY_MS; //it will fire every 100 milliseconds
timerFrequency100MS.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(oneHundredMS_Elapsed);
timerFrequency100MS.Start();
```

Comment: This takes care of the questions of thread safety.  Consider placing the setTimerBodyFinished call in a finally block to make sure it always gets called.